# Ionic return value to previous view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a form that works as follows:

Main View has list of all the fields
e.g 1.  Merchant, 2. Amount 3. Date

The form is fairly long.  Instead of doing a multistep form, I am hoping to do the following:

1. Tap on the Merchant to open a select merchant view and select merchant to return the value to main view.
2. Tap on Amount to enter amount view.  Once the value is entered return the value to main view
3. Tap on date to enter the date view.  Once the date is selected return int to the main view.

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a service to share data between the controllers associated with each view.

```
app.service('YourService', function($q) {
  return {
    details: 
      {
        name: 'Merchant_1',         //Some default values
        amount: 100,
        date: ""
      }
    ,
    getDetails: function() {
      return this.details
    },
    setDetails: function(name,amount,date) {
      this.details.name = name;
      this.details.amount = amount;
      this.details.date = date;
    },
    setName: function(name){
      this.details.name = name;
    }
  }
});
```

and in your controllers inject 'YourService'. For eg. the controller for the merchant view.

```
app.controller( 'MerchantViewCtrl', function( $scope, YourService ) {
      var onSelect = function(MerchantName){
           YourService.setName(MerchantName); 
      }
});
```

Select Merchant view

```
 <select ng-click="onSelect(merchant.name)" ng-options="merchant in merchantsList">
 </select>
```

and in your main view controller

```
app.controller( 'MainViewCtrl', function( $scope, YourService ) {
      var details = YourService.getDetails();
      $scope.name = details.name;
      $scope.amount = details.amount;
      $scope.date = details.date;
});
```